# Change rules on local server so URLs don't include file extensions using MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running a local server via [MAMP PRO](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/). Currently my urls (expect index.php) require the file extension suffix. For example:
site/page.php

How do I change rewrite rules it is
site/page

I've attempted adding a htaccess file but it has no effect on file structure.  Is there another way to do this via MAMP?

Comment: So how would you destinguish file.php from file.html or file.css...use framework with properly written .htaccess.

Comment: Here is good guide on url rewrite https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: @magic-sudo I don't need to distinguish based on file type (not my question)

Comment: I find it hard to believe this question was necessary. There are dozens of trivial URL rewriting questions posted each day.

Comment: Specific to MAMP?

Comment: What indicated MAMP-specificness here? Any failure you got with following a tutorial or 08/15 example?

Comment: @Sam: the `mod_rewrite` in Apache, WAMP, LAMP and MAMP should be the same (possibly with exceptions for case-sensitivity of underlying file system, but then that's not a change in the web server _per se_).

Comment: @mario .htaccess file doesn't have an effect

Comment: Readfirst: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/02/the-htaccess-file-and-mamp-pro.html / VirtualHost section -- Also "MAMP" is not relevant. The concrete webserver being used is.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are only PHP files you can add .htaccess file to your directory.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also if you are not familiar with `RewriteEngine` check https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ for future reading